# Win32_InstalledProgramFramework not working properly?

Tags: powershell, winapi, frameworks, wmi

I'm coming in with a super complicated Question which is kind of related to PowerShell Scripting as well.

Normally, since Win7 (at least according to the Documentation) - Windows should expose this Class:
`Win32_InstalledProgramFramework`

This Class would basically be able to return Frameworks used by this Program (VisualC, Java, .NET and more) based on the ProgramID which I got returned from `Win32_InstalledWin32Program`.

## Current Script

```
$Programs = Get-WMIObject Win32_InstalledWin32Program | Select-Object Name, ProgramID
$Result = ForEach ($Program in $Programs) {
    Write-Output $Program.Name
    Write-Output $Program.ProgramID
    $Name = $Program.Name
    $ProgramID = $Program.ProgramID

    $FMapp = Get-WMIObject Win32_InstalledProgramFramework -Filter "ProgramID = '$ProgramID'"

    ForEach ($FM in $FMapp) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Name'               = $Name
            'ProgramID'          = $ProgramID
            'FrameworkPublisher' = $FM.FrameworkPublisher
            'FrameworkName'      = $FM.FrameworkName
            'FrameworkVersion'   = $FM.FrameworkVersion
        }
        Write-Output $FM.FrameworkPublisher
    }
}

$Result | Out-GridView`
```

I have checked that I have these classes in my WMI Namespace:

```
Get-WmiObject -list -recurse | Findstr Win32_InstalledProgramFramework

Win32_InstalledProgramFramework     {}                   {FrameworkName, FrameworkPublisher, FrameworkVersion, Frame...
```

... and I have checked that I get the ProgramID from `Win32_InstalledWin32Program`.

Somehow this is and remains undefined, or at least does not return any Data.

Currently using: latest Win11 ARM Release for Parallels (developing on MacM2)

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Net Library originally was incremental that new version of Net on contained changes from previous versions.  So initially you needed 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2.  I believe starting in 4.3 each version contained everything and you didn't need the older versions.  Then came Core.  The purpose of Core was to have one version of library that would work on Windows, MAC, Linux without app being different for each OS.  Core was done in pieces because entire structure was changed.  You should be using Core on a MAC and using the RunTime library on a ARM.

Comment: Yeah but the thing is that this sadly doesnt solve my Issue. I need some kind of way to detect which runtimes are being used :( But I really appreciate your answer 

Comment: With Core there is one one runtime.   Older versions will not run without the Net Library(s) installed.  You should run only with Core 5 or later where you can check version of Core so you have forward/backward compatibility.  Trying to do that with Net and Core on a MAC will be very difficult.  There will be too many changes between libraries.

Comment: Yeah I get that :) But the Thing is I only used the VM for Development. - Final Stage will be a default x86/x64 Windows. Most likely Win10 LTSC 2019. And its not just .NET. I would need to be able to detect if a Application is using Visual C, Java or .NET and this Class would‘ve been perfect for this usecase.

Comment: See following : https://xkln.net/blog/please-stop-using-win32product-to-find-installed-software-alternatives-inside/?force_isolation=true